# 777 Permissions not working NTFS FSTAB

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab

I am adding an external drive to my owncloud server. The drive needs to have permissions for the PHP program (www-data). The drive in question is a NTFS at 777 with the owner as me and the user group www-data. It still lacks the permission.

I made a test account on my computer and added it to the user group as well but it can not access the drive.

Yes I am using FSTAB and yes the umask is set to 000, Any ideas?

Comment: You must give permissions to the directory where it is mounted.The NTFS file system does not accept permits Gnu / Linux

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `fstab` entry? That would help determine what values are being set.

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal

```
gksudo nautilus
```

You can manage it through the window that it opens.